# Windows 8 - XAML/C# How to set aspect ratio of camera

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My Microsoft HD web-cam supports 16:9 aspect ratio. I can preview and capture in 16:9 aspect ratio from Microsoft LifeCam utility.

In my application, the preview only shows in 4:3 aspect ratio. Is there any way to set it to 16:9? I googled it, searched MSDN APIs but couldn't find a way to do it.

The code I have so far looks like this:

XAML
    `<CaptureElement x:Name="CameraCaptureElement" Stretch="Uniform" ></CaptureElement>`

C# Code

```
private async void InitializeCamera()
{
MediaCapture mediaCaptureMgr = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
CameraCaptureElement.Source = mediaCaptureMgr;
await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API for setting the aspect ratio using MediaCapture, so you may want to consider using CameraCaptureUI instead, if aspect ratio selection is important to you, though CameraCaptureUI will leave the choice of source aspect ratio in the hands of the user (you can, however, programmatically control the starting aspect ratio of the cropped image if the user chooses to crop the original capture).

Check out the following sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac

It shows how to use the CameraCaptureUI object to set the aspect ratio for cropping, which is the best you can do programmatically, I believe. Here's the relevant code:

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
Size aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
dialog.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
```

You can also restrict the maximum resolution that the user can select, but not the capture aspect ratio.

When the CameraCaptureUI is invoked via CaptureFileAsync, the user has the option to adjust the aspect ratio via the Camera Options button, as shown below:

[image: Camera Options]

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `Clip` on your `CameraCaptureElement` to clip the preview to desired aspect ratio. Then after you capture a photo - you would need to crop it.

Comment: I have some issue related to this. When continuously capturing the photos in high resolution [1280x800] in 1366x768 surface device , every time it seems like a jump back and forth in the screen because of the image just flashes on the screen over the capture element. I set Height & Width of the Capture element to 1228.788 and 768 as per  maintaing the aspect ratio. But it is not handling the effect. Can you provide any guidelines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'd ask a separate question here or on MSDN Forums for better visibility.

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808547/how-to-capture-high-resolution-video-and-capture-photo-from-it-in-windows-8-1-i

Comment: sorry. That was done by me with any other choice. Actually i just avoided using the resolution which makes the problem.