# Issue with aspect ratio / zoom level changing when using MediaCapture?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10

I am using [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) along with [CapturePreview](https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaCaptureWPF) to create a preview stream on a Surface Pro tablet. I am taking photos periodically with a timer using

```
CapturePhotoToStreamAsync()
```

Whenever a photo is taken though, the preview stream zooms out slightly as if it is changing the resolution or aspect ratio or something similar.

I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808547/how-to-capture-high-resolution-video-and-capture-photo-from-it-in-windows-8-1-i?rq=1), which sounds exactly the same, but I can't seem to resolve it regardless of the resolutions set.

This is the bit of code I have to grab `Bitmap` objects from the stream:

```
using (var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    await mediaCap.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProps, randomAccessStream);

    randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
    using (var ioStream = randomAccessStream.AsStream())
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = ioStream;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        bitmapImage.Freeze();
    }
}
```

`imageProps` is being set to 1280x720, the same resolution as the preview object. This wouldn't be a huge issue if it only happened occasionally, but I need to grab frames frequently (multiple times per second), and it looks very jarring.

Edit:

Something to note is that the issue only occurs on the mentioned Surface Pro tablet (2736x1824 @200%), it doesn't appear to occur on a 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: What is bitmapImage's actual size? And from your description, the `Image` control's source is always the `CapturePreview`, you don't display the captured image at all, right?

Comment: @kennyzx `bitmapImage.PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` is also 1280x720. And yes, the source of the image element is always `CapturePreview`, any captured image is just passed around to be used elsewhere.

Comment: Is the timer’s interval make a difference? I tried capturing once per second, and that didn’t seem to affect the video preview.

Comment: @kennyzx It doesn't appear to, I have the capture hooked up to a button now, and the issue occurs whenever a capture takes place. I should add that the issue only appears to occur on the Surface Tablet I mentioned, presumable because of the aspect ratio? It doesn't occur on a 1920x1080 dev machine.

Comment: @TheWhetherMan I can't see your issue on my laptop (2560 x 1440  @225%) Do you have any screenshots with comparison?

Comment: @TheWhetherMan Which version of Surface Pro??  Is that the 4th gen or 5th gen?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT It's the 5th generation model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up finding was this change:

From:

```
await _mediaCaptureObject.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    VideoDeviceId = deviceList?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Camera Name"))?.Id,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
});
```

To:

```
await _mediaCaptureObject.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    VideoDeviceId = deviceList?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Camera Name"))?.Id,
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
});
```

This doesn't really explain the issue I was seeing, since I was setting the `ImageEncodingProperties` to the same resolution as the stream when capturing the photo. Anyway, the default `PhotoCaptureSource` is `Auto`, which must've been using the `Photo` mode instead of `VideoPreview`. Once I changed this, the issue stopped appearing.